# DEP6100 Error in Deploying Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT application to Windows 10 Mobile 10.0.10586

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows Phone 8.1/WinRT solution in Visual Studio 2015.  I upgraded my phone to Windows 10 Mobile OS 10.0.10586.11 and I could not deploy the application.

2>Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.': 
2>DeviceException - The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.
2>Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

Comment: I have been having this issue since build 10581. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Nice to know that I am not the only one.  I heard that Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 will be out on Nov 30, 2015.  I am hoping that a fix for this will be included.  I am going to wait for that update and will try it again.

Comment: If you are deploying your app into device, first check if your app is already installed in the phone. If so, un-install and then run VS 2015. I had same issue, deleting the app from device solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed.  I downloaded and installed the latest update for Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update1.  I have also updated the phone to Windows 10 Mobile 10.0.10586.29.  After that, I was able to deploy my Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Answer (score -1):

You must have:

- Latest Windows 10;
- Latest Windows 10 SDK;
- Latest Windows 10 Mobile Emulators

**UPDATED**

Also, you can try to remove you device from PC

Comment: I am on the Fast Ring Insider for Windows 10 and so I am sure I have the latest OS version.  I have downloaded the latest SDK and emulator but it did not help.

Comment: Also, you can try to remove you device from PC